# jQuery dynamic CSS attribute assignment

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, css, safari

Assigning CSS attributes on-the-fly in jQuery is easy enough.  e.g.

```
$('#element').css('fontWeight','bold');
```

However, the dynamic assignment I currently need to do is rather more messy.  In order to have background gradient assignments to work on a range of browsers I need to do

```
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);

$('#element').css('backgroundImage','value')
```

called repeatedly will not work since jQuery simply overwrites the previously written version. How else can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do class :

```
BackgroundClass
{
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
}
```

and add this class to the element :

```
$('#element').addClass("BackgroundClass");
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution would be to create a class with the required properties, add it to your stylesheet and use .addClass to assign class to the element dynamically.

CSS:

```
.gradientClass{
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
background-image:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(r,g,b,a),rgba(r1,g1,b1,a1) 10%);
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('#element').addClass('gradientClass');
```

Comment: +1. Handling a class name is much cleaner than directly manipulating the css properties.

Comment: Pretty much the same as the first answer so I decided to accept the first one.  Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @DroidOS The topmost answer is not always the first one. Mine was made before if you check the time :P Anyways doesnt matter as long as you got what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery why don't you use this plug-in?
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/gradient

You can then easily use it:

```
$('.gradient').gradient({ from: '003366', to: '333333' });
```

Comment: Yikes!  YAPL strikes again!